# What is the 'best practise' to manage Multilingual stores in Magento?

Tags: multistore, url, language

In Magento, multilingual sites are managed with store views, then we can choose different approach regarding how to manage the URLs:

1. "Add Store Code to URLs" (a backend setting)
2. Have different domain for each store views ([Multi-Site, Multi-Domain Setup](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup))

The first option will add store code at the end of the URL so if the code is **en**, the URL will be `MYDOMAIN/en/`.

This option sounds good but the note under it says:
"*Warning! When using Store Code in URLs, in some cases system may not work properly if URLs without Store Codes are specified in the third party services (e.g. PayPal etc.).*"

**Is it safe ?**

The second option is only possible if you have more than one domain and let you assign the domain to store views.

My question is what are the best practices?

There are other better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

There is a third solution:
Neither use the first nor the second. Then the storeview is only reachable via manual change and will be saved in a cookie/session.

I think your options are best practice. Without the possibility to identify the storeview by the url, it is not possible to copy and paste urls and end on the same page as your friend.

And in the end, the customer decides what fits best for him.

Comment: the cookie/session stuff is a default behavior or I'm wrong ?

Comment: no you are not wrong. There is a store_change_block or something. What I wanted to emphasize is, that having the storeview somehow in the url is important :)

Comment: You need to be careful with this as it will have dramatic SEO issues if you are looking for your store to be indexed under multiple languages.